# Can't create file elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run a django app on eb. My goal is to create a cron script in /etc/cron.d at deployment time that runs django jobs. I tried to create it using a an eb configuration file, but so far I've been unable to create any file anywhere (manually checked by sshing into the host).

Platform: Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.9

The content of `cron.config` looks like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/cron_job":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      * * * * * root echo "Cron running at "`date` > /home/ec2-user/cron_job.log
```

What I've tried is following. In all cases, app deploys but no file created.

1. Placing `cron.config` in `.ebextensions` folder.
2. Placing `cron.config` in `.platform/hook/postdeploy` folder. Log says "The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...".
3. Specify file location as /tmp/cron_job.
4. Specify file location as /home/ec2-user/cron_job.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **nothing wrong** with your `cron.config` and it creates `/etc/cron.d/cron_job`. It works as expected as I run it on my own EB application. Whatever is happening is due to some other factors/code which is not shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where did you place `cron.config`?

Comment: Actually I realized that I was ssh'ing into the wrong host It worked after all, thanks!